# How can I write an .includes() plus .where() on both top model and associated model in Rails4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, arel

I didn't have any idea what was going wrong with this query:

```
@customers =
      Customer.includes(:phone_numbers, :emails)
        .select("first_name, last_name, zip_code, customers.id, street1, street2")
        .where(:merchant_id => environment)
        .where("phone_numbers.number ~* :key",
               :key => key, :digits => digits)
```

It was working fine in Rails3.

I stumbled onto some documentation [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) that helped me resolve it in Rails4, but I'd like to know if there is a better way to write this query.

It produces the following (this is gnarly...):

```
"SELECT first_name, last_name, zip_code, customers.id, street1, street2, "customers"."id" AS t0_r0, "customers"."account_id" AS t0_r1, "customers"."first_name" AS t0_r2, "customers"."last_name" AS t0_r3, "customers"."street1" AS t0_r4, "customers"."street2" AS t0_r5, "customers"."city_id" AS t0_r6, "customers"."city" AS t0_r7, "customers"."state" AS t0_r8, "customers"."state_id" AS t0_r9, "customers"."zip_code" AS t0_r10, "customers"."country" AS t0_r11, "customers"."municipality" AS t0_r12, "customers"."latitude" AS t0_r13, "customers"."longitude" AS t0_r14, "customers"."location" AS t0_r15, "customers"."customer_type" AS t0_r16, "customers"."notes" AS t0_r17, "customers"."birthday" AS t0_r18, "customers"."merchant_id" AS t0_r19, "customers"."gmaps" AS t0_r20, "customers"."marketing" AS t0_r21, "customers"."communication_method" AS t0_r22, "customers"."account_status" AS t0_r23, "customers"."account_type" AS t0_r24, "customers"."created_at" AS t0_r25, "customers"."updated_at" AS t0_r26, "customers"."api_customer_id" AS t0_r27, "customers"."api_updated_at" AS t0_r28, "phone_numbers"."id" AS t1_r0, "phone_numbers"."customer_id" AS t1_r1, "phone_numbers"."account_id" AS t1_r2, "phone_numbers"."contact_id" AS t1_r3, "phone_numbers"."number" AS t1_r4, "phone_numbers"."country_code" AS t1_r5, "phone_numbers"."area_code" AS t1_r6, "phone_numbers"."extension" AS t1_r7, "phone_numbers"."created_at" AS t1_r8, "phone_numbers"."updated_at" AS t1_r9, "emails"."id" AS t2_r0, "emails"."customer_id" AS t2_r1, "emails"."account_id" AS t2_r2, "emails"."contact_id" AS t2_r3, "emails"."address" AS t2_r4, "emails"."created_at" AS t2_r5, "emails"."updated_at" AS t2_r6 
FROM "customers" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "phone_numbers" ON "phone_numbers"."customer_id" = "customers"."id" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "emails" ON "emails"."customer_id" = "customers"."id" 
WHERE "customers"."merchant_id" = 29 AND (phone_numbers.number ~* '424298')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't selecting any of the fields in `phone_numbers` or `emails` I think you want to use `join` not `includes`. Tricky bit is to make the `LEFT OUTER` work.

http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins

Something like this maybe.

```
Customer.
  select("first_name, last_name, zip_code, customers.id, street1, street2").
  joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN phone_numbers ON phone_numbers.customer_id = customers.id").
  joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN emails ON emails.customer_id = customers.id").
  where(:merchant_id => environment).
  where("phone_numbers.number ~* :key", :key => key, :digits => digits)
```